# AIR App crashes at Extension context creation on one machine but works fine on others

Tags: air, flash-builder, desktop-application, air-native-extension, ane

I am using an ane in our AIR application which works fine except on some machines(I have access to one such machine).

I tried other ane on that machine and that is running just fine.

Now after spending hours and hours I have come to know that the app crashes at this line:

> objExtCtx = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("device.boost.NativeAdd",null);

this call never returns and my app crashes :(

What's more is everything works when I debug the application on that same machine.

This problem is common but no solution is available.

 Any help will be appreciated.

 Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer :)

seems like my c++ code was using some managed code and hence was dependent on .net framework and by default the target was set to .net 4.0.

Now my code crashes on the machines which have .net 3.5 or lower.

I think changing the target .net version should do fine..will update my answer if it does.

EDIT1: seems like vs2008 is needed to change the dependency to .net 3.5 and that too full version, as express version doesn't contain all the libraries required in the project.

So now the required platform becomes **.net 4.0** .